# "configure: error: libapr-1 not found"

Tags: windows, mingw, configure

I'm getting this error message when trying to configure an application. I have apr installed and it's location added to the PATH. There are a few files there, including `libapr-1.a` and `libapr-1-0.dll`
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you done `make install` in your `libapr` folder ?

Comment: @moskito-x, yes. It's installed.